# Keycloak: realm.getDefaultLocale() method is `DefaultLocaleSelectorProvider.java` is not returning the default locale set for the realm

Tags: keycloak, locale

I have a default locale added for one of the realms in `REALM` table in `DEFAULT_LOCALE` column. For some reason this locale is not considered when I am visiting the login page. I then extended this provider and added my own custom provider. And when I am printing the value for `realm.getDefaultLocale()` in my provider, it is showing me null. I am assuming realm model should have everything populated. Is this not correct assumption?